# Data structure complementary of BloomFilters

Tags: java, data-structures, bloom-filter

Are there any (probabilistic) data structures for set membership test that might produce false negative but not false positives? I'm looking for something similar to BloomFilters but with complementary behavior: If the answer to 'mightContain' is 'yes' then the set is guaranteed to contain the element; if the answer is 'no' then the set might still contain the element.

Comment: You can easily make this by just having a fixed-sized set; after the set overflows, you don't add any new elements. This will match your criteria, but not have any good probabilistic guarantees. Do you want something with the same sorts of probabilistic guarantees as Bloom filters?

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/a-probabilistic-set-with-no-false-positives